# Is there a way to get a list of selected module versions, but only for modules within the pruned graph?

Tags: go

Since version 1.17 go no longer loads the entire module graph, but, with the introduced concept of pruned graph, only a part of it. A pruned graph can be viewed using `go mod graph`. However, when I want to see the selected module version within that pruned graph using `go list -m all`, it traverses the entire graph and prints the selected versions for all modules (including the ones that are not part of the pruned graph).

Is there a way to get/print selected versions **only for the modules inside (within) the pruned graph**? Any go command/tool.

Thank you!